How to compare variation within and between populations for data that are correlated?
Let's say you have two populations of humans and a set of attributes. I would like to know if there is more variation between the two populations than within the populations. The reason I am asking this question is that I often hear that there is more variation within a human "racial group" than between human "racial" groups. I don't understand how this can be true if it's also possible to classify people into racial groups based on what alleles they have.
My understanding is that classification is based on the fact that certain alleles are correlated with other alleles for group a, whereas for group b a different correlation amongst alleles exists. And it is this difference that makes classification between the groups  possible.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me how these two "facts" can be reconciled.

Is this a statistics question? I think this may be better asked at the Biology stackexchange. It's mostly about the definition of race. Take a look at Do humans have enough biological differences to be grouped into races or subspecies?.
